# Making DIV appear smoothly with fadeIn

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

So I've got two Divs that are linked (graphically). I want these to separate over a period of time. As of now, they just Bounce out in a matter of a millisecond.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/447TH/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("article").fadeIn('slow', function(){
     $('.segment1').fadeIn(3000);
}); 
});
```

If you take A look at the JSfiddle, I'm sure that you will be able to figure out what I mean if my description is vague. Thank you in advance!

Comment: FYi it's `$(document).ready(function () {` not `$('document').ready(function () {`

Comment: instead use `slideDown(1000);` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/447TH/4/)

Comment: @j08691 I wrote this on my tablet, big typo from my side. Thanks for correcting me! :)

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/447TH/9/)**

Instead of using fadeIn use the maxHeight technique.

**JS:**

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('article').animate({maxHeight:999},3000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.segment1').animate({opacity:1},1000, function(){
            //do something after segment revealed
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

**Css:**

```
article{
    ...
    display:block;
    ...
    max-height: 0;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that the animation doesnt start from the top. It starts partially half-way from the top. Is this anything you know how to fix?

Comment: @Joel Check the updated solution -- now it animated from the top and not half-way.

Comment: hey -- did the solution worked for you? if so please close the question by accepting a answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use `slideDown` In Place Of `fadeIn`

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $("article").fadeIn('slow', function(){
         $('.segment1').slideDown(5000);
    }); 
});
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/447TH/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the working solution, but the paragraph overlaps with the content above sadly. @imran Solved it for me. However i'm gonna +1 for your effort and your partly working solution. Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$("article").fadeIn('slow', function(){
     $('.segment1').fadeIn('slow');
}); 
});
```

Try this i think its work

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?